# Rails - Sidekiq status is empty in Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for background processing and [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) for job progress tracking.

Using:

- Ruby 2.5.1
- Rails 5.1.6
- Redis 4.0.1
- Sidekiq 5.1.3
- Sidekiq-status 1.0.2

Redis is up and running. Background process is working normal. I put binding.pry in process and start testing:

```
job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)

Sidekiq::Status::queued?      job_id => false
Sidekiq::Status::working?     job_id => false
Sidekiq::Status::complete?    job_id => false
Sidekiq::Status::failed?      job_id => false

status = Sidekiq::Status::status(job_id) => {} (empty)
```

When I open web monitor `http://localhost:3000/sidekiq/statuses` for sidekiq, stasuses are empty.

job_id that I get from app console is different than `"almighty:16288:dea0b989e20f"`.

After running `redis-cli` and `keys *` I get:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "almighty:16288:dea0b989e20f:workers"
2) "stat:failed:2018-08-10"
3) "queues"
4) "stat:failed"
5) "stat:processed:2018-08-10"
6) "almighty:16288:dea0b989e20f"
7) "processes"
8) "stat:processed"
9) "sidekiq:status:"
```

And then hgetall `"sidekiq:status:"`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall "sidekiq:status:"
 1) "update_time"
 2) "1533929922"
 3) "at"
 4) "23.529411764705884"
 5) "total"
 6) "100"
 7) "pct_complete"
 8) "23"
 9) "message"
10) "Clustering data..."
```

So, some data about process is here, but not by job_id. And when the job is done, "sidekiq:status:" is gone. I assume, someting is wrong with storing data in redis from sidekiq?

**/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:**

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-status'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 } #, url: ENV['REDIS_URL']
  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes

  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_server_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes

  # accepts :expiration (optional)
  Sidekiq::Status.configure_client_middleware config, expiration: 30.minutes

  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end
```

**/config/initializers/redis.rb:**

```
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
```

**/config/application.rb:**

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://localhost:6379/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }
```

Comment: Anyone got any solution for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't solve this problem. I just moved that data to the database.